# Python getting time difference

Tags: python, database, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I am working in a dataframe in Pandas and I have to get the time difference from datettime grouped by the identifier.
Here is the dataframe

```python
    Identifier                   datetime
0   AL011851                     00:00:00
1   AL011851                     06:00:00             
2   Al011851                     12:00:00
```

When I run this code

```python
hurricane_df = hurricane_df.groupby('identifier')['datetime'].diff().fillna(0)
```

hurricane_df

I keep getting an attribute error 
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute '_aggregate_item_by_item'

Anyway around this?

Comment: Use `hurricane_df['datetime'] = hurricane_df['datetime'].dt.time`

Comment: @jezrael thank you but now im running into another issue, I want to get the time difference using this `hurricane_df = hurricane_df.groupby('identifier')['datetime'].diff().fillna(0)
hurricane_df` and I keep getting an error saying AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute '_aggregate_item_by_item'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set same dates in datetimes by:

```
hurricane_df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(hurricane_df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), 
                                          format='%H:%M:%S')

print (hurricane_df)
  identifier            datetime
0   AL011851 1900-01-01 00:00:00
1   AL011851 1900-01-01 06:00:00
2   Al011851 1900-01-01 12:00:00
```

Or convert column to timedeltas:

```
hurricane_df['datetime'] = pd.to_timedelta(hurricane_df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
print (hurricane_df)
  identifier datetime
0   AL011851 00:00:00
1   AL011851 06:00:00
2   Al011851 12:00:00

hurricane_df = hurricane_df.groupby('identifier')['datetime'].diff().fillna(0) 
print (hurricane_df)
0   00:00:00
1   06:00:00
2   00:00:00
Name: datetime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```